# How to avoid editor.getSession().insert(...) to trigger a change event?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

[The initial title was: Prevent actions from keyboard in Ace Editor but catch them]

I use Ace Editor in order to create a real time collaboration platform. I found questions more or less similar to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050128/applydeltas-in-ace-editor) or [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ace-discuss/cIYsOw8Vl5g) but none of them are suitable to my case.

There is this event that causes a problem if there are multiple users writing:

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function(e) {
    // action = e.action
    // newString = e.lines
    // index = editor.session.doc.positionToIndex(editor.selection.getCursor())
}
```

When the user wants to enter something (keypress event) I want to catch the action, the content added or removed, and the index of the cursor (not `(row, col)`). The insertion or deletion **should be prevented** at this step. These three parameters should be the inputs of the function `sendDelta(action, string, index)`.

For simplification, the function `sendDelta(action, string, index)` should call `insertDelta(action, string, index)` which is responsible to insert. But this insertion should not wake up the event for the content change.

To sum up, I want to catch only what comes from the keyboard, not the insertions done through the function `insertDelta(action, string, index)`.

**EDIT**

As @a_user suggested, I think the design of my application does not make sense. So I would like to ask a question very close to the first one.

Let's say I have a function `changeFromServer(action, string, index)` which receives the information from the network and applies the changes. Then the insertion would trigger the on change event which would send back the information to the network. This would create an infinite loop.

I am not sure whether or not my explanations were clear. If not, [this user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ace-discuss/cIYsOw8Vl5g) had the same problem than me and his description looks better than mine. By the way, I do not understand the answer provided there.

Comment: if you prevent the change event, many things will be wrong, e.g. cursor position after insertion, undo grouping, why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: You are write, I slightly change my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a flag to know when change event is called from changeFromServer

```
var fromServer = false
function changeFromServer() {
    fromServer = true
    // call applyDelta here
    fromServer = false
}
doc.on("change", function(e) { 
    if (fromServer) return;
})
```